# Can't understand the meaning of a sentence

Tags: english

I'm translating the following video from English to Russian: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjCclg_TU0o - it's an interview with John Cusack. I can't get what's the meaning of what he said on 3:20 - 3:33. And can't understand a few words as well.

Could anybody write and explain it to me?
Thank you!)

Comment: Sorry, this is not on topic here, but could be migrated to [SE ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @robert this is a good idea, could somebody do it please?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you are on the right forum for this sort of question, but here it is anyway:

> What I thought it was sort of a...uhh..kind of a funny, kitch, black,
>   absurd idea, and I thought if I'm gonna be self-referential, sort of
>   postmodern..if somebody's gonna do that they are gonna be mean to
>   me..it might as well be me..so yeah, I said..I should take shots at
>   myself.. you know..and then..but all movies are risks..

I can't say for sure without watching the whole interview, but it seems that he wrote or co-wrote the script for his role in a movie. He is quipping that when he learned that the role was going to be self-referential - connected with his personal character, he was aware that the script writer would necessarily have to be mean to him, so he decided to write it himself - personally take shots at himself and save others the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> Well I thought it was sort of a kind of a funny kitsch, black, absurd idea and I thought if I'm going to be self-referential and sort of postmodern.  And you know if somebody's going to do that and they are going to be mean to me, it might as well be me.  So you know I said, I should take shots at myself you know (and then) but all movies are a risk (so you just) I thought we could do it and I worked with a friend Steve Pankoid who I'd done High Fidelity and Grosse Pointe with and you know it was just a fun, weird, bizarre comedy.